# Alert command isnt working on my javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to make this simple game with javascript on rock paper scissors. The alert command is not showing when I open it up on both Microsoft edge and Chrome. Here is my code, I need helping out on this.

http://pastebin.com/qsPTPWn6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do var compare = function().... is defining a function. 
so you have a call this function to get a result.
try do

```
compare("scissors", computerChoice); //at the end of script
```

This is just an example, assuming you will play scissor every time

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call the function. so it is better to give a function name for calling it, try this  :

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
}
else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
}
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} 
console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

var compare = toCompare(userChoice, computerChoice);

function toCompare(userChoice, computerChoice){
    if (userChoice === computerChoice){
         alert("The result is a tie!");
    }
    if(userChoice === "rock"){
        if (computerChoice === "scissors"){
            alert("rock wins");
        }
        else{
            alert("paper wins");
        }
    }
    if(userChoice === "paper"){
        if (computerChoice === "rock"){
            alert("paper wins");
        }
        else{
            alert("scissors wins");
        }
    }
    if(userChoice === "scissors"){
        if (computerChoice2 === "paper"){
            alert("scissors wins");
        }
        else{
            alert("rock wins");
        }
    }
};
```